# Use iPod touch to connect phone to car stereo

Tags: bluetooth, sound-volume

I have a iPod touch 4, paired to Boss 758DBI in-dash car stereo. Why can't I use Bluetooth on iPod to pair my phone?

Would like to do this so that I can have a handsfree conversation through my car stereo.
My iPod has a built-in mic and Bluetooth and a dock in my car.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use your iPod as a bridge between your phone and the stereo. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Try pairing your phone to the stereo. Some devices allow multipoint connections so you can have an iPod and a phone both paired and connected at the same time. My Motorola bluetooth headphones allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth devices are designed to function under certain "profiles". This is what allows a headset to work with Skype versus Bluetooth headphones which might work with iTunes. Apple's iOS uses very restrictive setup with their Bluetooth profiles. Because of this you cannot pair an iPod touch to a mobile phone.

Here is a list of the supported Bluetooth profiles: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

Answer (score 0):

iPods aren't set up (nor do they have drivers) to pair to arbitrary devices. It might be possible (though I doubt it) to make an app that'd pretend to be a Bluetooth headset to a paired phone; I don't know of any apps that offer that feature.

Does your phone have a physical line-out (even through an adapter) that you could connect to your car stereo?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual for your car stereo, you should be able to pair your iPhone to the stereo to enable the Bluetooth phone functionality. Just follow the instructions in the manual. Whether or not you have your iPod Touch attached to the stereo's dock or AUX input is irrelevant; the Touch is not involved in the Bluetooth connection at all. The Bluetooth connection, the AUX connection and the iPod (dock) connections are completely separate inputs to the stereo, and you select which input you want using the stereo's MODE (Input Select) switch.